# Делать ли каскад методов асинхронными, если они могут возвращать просто Task<T>

Tags: c#, .net, async-await, асинхронность, clr

Терзает вопрос, найти внятный ответ не могу. Гуглится не то.

Вот у меня есть действительно асинхронный метод, в котором несколько `await`'ов. Этот метод вызывается на более верхнем уровне:

```
public async Task<Result> UpperLevelMethod()
{
    return await _component.RealyAsyncMethod();
}
```

Ну и так далее, по всем слоям приложения.

Но ведь по идее, можно написать так:

```
public Task<Result> UpperLevelMethod()
{
    return _component.RealyAsyncMethod();
}
```

И вызов `await UpperLevelMethod()` будет корректно отрабатывать. И, на сколько я понимаю, этот метод даже лучше, т.к. не будет создаваться дополнительные экземпляры `IAsyncStateMachine`, поправьте, если я не прав.

Интересно, что авторы статей и книг в красках описывают последствия упаковки/распаковки, но этот момент как-то упускается в разделе про асинхронность.

Есть ли какие-то подводные камни, у такого вызова? Либо, в случаях, когда не нужно делать асинхронное продолжение, можно (а возможно даже *лучше*) делать метод не асинхронным?

**P.S.** Тот же Скит описывает, что для проверки аргументов лучше делать так:

```
public Task<Result> UpperLevelMethod(string arg)
{
    /*
    Проверка аргумента и выброс исключения в случае ошибки
    */
    return _component.RealyAsyncMethod();
}
```

Но он говорит именно про проверку аргументов, чтобы она проходила в синхронном режиме. Об оптимизации - ничего.

**Update:** 
Консольное приложение, собраное в релизе, с таким кодом:

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    Task.Run(Foo5);
}

static async Task<int> Foo1() => await Task.FromResult(5);

static Task<int> Foo2() => Foo1();

static Task<int> Foo3() => Foo2();

static Task<int> Foo4() => Foo3();

static Task<int> Foo5() => Foo4();
```

весит 8 192 байт, при добавлении `await`'ов - 10 240 байт.

Comment: Я понимаю точно так же как и вы, тоже бы не вызывал лишние async/await

Comment: Годится, но только пока вам не надо обработать результат.

Comment: @Monk, собственно, в вопросе я и написал про продолжение.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Совершенно верно, лучше не писать лишний раз `async` если код работает и без него. Нет никаких причин писать лишние слова `async` и `await`.